# ASP.NET database is not working, I couldn't connect to the database

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, visual-studio, web

I'm not very familiar with ASP.NET. How comes my database is not working in my project? what am I missing exactly?
ASP.NET in Visual Studio
[image: Here's the Server Explorer]

The website works when I run the project but once I interact with the database it shows me this error:
"Something went wrong! Contact your devloper
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

[image: It shows this too]

Comment: have you the correct host and users, mostöy this comes from that the server hasn't tcpip enabled and the sql browser isn't active, that said, youshouldn't have a server conencted directly to the internet

Comment: Run the SQL IDE for your database (Sql Server Management Studio for MS SQL Server). See if that can connect. If not, debug your problem from there. If it does, then you have a problem in the syntax of your connection string.